# Best way to add local videos to app?

Tags: ios, video, media

I'm developing a tutorial app that contains videos that show you instruction. I'm wondering what the best method of storing videos on the app would be, storing the videos directly on the app or providing a URL to the video and placing it in the app?

Answer (score 2):

**1. Adding the video file**

Add the video (lets call it video.m4v) to your Xcode project

**2. Checking your video is into the Bundle**

Open the Project Navigator cmd + 1

Then select your project root > your Target > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.

Your video MUST be here. If it's not, then you should add it using the plus button

**3. Code**

Open your View Controller and write this code.

import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    playVideo()
}

private func playVideo() {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType:"m4v") else {
        debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
        return
    }
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There are advantages and disadvantages to each.

Bundling video with app advantages:

- self contained, does not need connectivity
- easy to test
- don't need a server side streaming infrastructure

Providing a URL to stream video from:

- Easy to update video after the app has been distributed - don't need to re-release app
- App size is smaller as you don't have the video bundled
- no using storage on app to store videos

There is also sort of hybrid approach, where the app does not have the video but downloads it when it is first used. You could even have the app check for changes and download an updated version. This still means you are using device storage to store the videos. You also have to make sure that this meets the App Store guidelines and is not seen as changing the app from the reviewed version.

Answer (score 0):

Cheap and best way is to use App thinning. Add Videos in your bundle. Add that to App thinning(In Project - Target - Resource Tags).

In the app in collection view or tableview show video thumbnails (You will store it in resources) using plist array or Json array. When user clicks any cell download that particular video using NSBundleResourceRequest. Get the download url and show in AVPLayer.